# Difference between hide, close and show in qt

Tags: qt, qt5

What is the difference between hide,close and show of pushbutton or any widget in terms of memory?

Which is better if I don't want to use widget again?

Comment: have you tried reading the documentation for those slots?

Answer (score 18):

First as said @Hayt, [read](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html) the documentation.

For the actual answer:

1. `hide()` is the same as `setVisible(false)`.
2. `show()` is the same as `setVisible(true)`.
3. `close()` attempts to close the widget by triggering a `QCloseEvent`, if the event is accepted the result is:

   1. The same as calling `hide()` if `Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose` attribute is not set on the widget which is the default.
   2. The same as calling `deleteLater()` if `Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose` is set.

In term of memory, any of the 3 will not change anything (except for `close()` if you have set `Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose`). If you do not want to use the widget ever, the best is to delete it:

```
delete pointerToMyWidget;
```

or

```
pointerToMyWidget->deleteLater();
```

The second form is generally safer as the 1st one can be dangerous depending on where your write it. (e.g you delete it in a slot called by a signal emitted by the widget you delete).

Comment: You can delete (and release the memory) the widget with close(), just had to manage the signal.

Comment: Or you can delete it by calling `delete`.

Comment: @BenjaminT If you delete it with `delete`, make sure it has no parent first, or the parent will call `delete` on it a second time when it is destroyed.

Comment: @Valerio No, the child removes itself from its parent child list. This is done by the call `d->setParent_helper(0);` in `~QObject()`. So when the parent is destroyed, the deleted child will not be deleted a second time as it is not listed as a child anymore.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Qt](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qwidget.html), you can read this :

> CLOSE :
>   Closes this widget. Returns true if the widget was closed; otherwise
>   returns false.
>
> First it sends the widget a QCloseEvent. The widget is hidden if it
>   accepts the close event. If it ignores the event, nothing happens. The
>   default implementation of QWidget::closeEvent() accepts the close
>   event.
>
> If the widget has the Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose flag, the widget is also
>   deleted. A close events is delivered to the widget no matter if the
>   widget is visible or not.
>
> The QApplication::lastWindowClosed() signal is emitted when the last
>   visible primary window (i.e. window with no parent) with the
>   Qt::WA_QuitOnClose attribute set is closed. By default this attribute
>   is set for all widgets except transient windows such as splash
>   screens, tool windows, and popup menus.

.

> HIDE : Hides the widget. This function is equivalent to
>   setVisible(false).
>
> Note: If you are working with QDialog or its subclasses and you invoke
>   the show() function after this function, the dialog will be displayed
>   in its original position.

.

> SHOW : Shows the widget and its child widgets. This function is
>   equivalent to setVisible(true).

If you don't need to use your widget, call `close()`. You can manage the event to destroy your widget.

`hide()` only hides. It's only graphical, you can't see your widget but you don't destroy it.

But I think that the name fo the function are enough explicit to understand!