# Qt: What is the difference between close,destroy and delete later?

Tags: c++, qt, object, qtimer

What is the difference between close,destroy and deletelater.I want to kill/delete an object after timeout.

```
QTimer::singleShot(tim*1000, &qPopup, &QLabel::hide)
```

Here I had used hide to hide the object.If I use close instead of hide,does it delete the object after timeout? What about destroy ?

Comment: [Difference between hide, close and show in qt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39407564/difference-between-hide-close-and-show-in-qt)

Comment: What about delete later ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Close is just a mechanism to provide greater flexibility to the programmer since it can be use to perform special actions when your widget / window is closed (e.g. showing a save dialog instead of actually closing a window if the user has unsaved changes to a document). By default widgets only become hidden when closed and are not deleted. However there is an important exception to this. If all of your applications top level windows are closed then they all get deleted and the application exits.

This behaviour can be modified using the following function:

```
myWidget->setAttribute( Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose, true ); // Widget will be deleted automatically when closed
myWidget->setAttribute( Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose, false ); // Widget will not be deleted automatically when closed unless it's the last visible widget.
```

The deleteLater() function flags a widget for deletion but nothing is deleted straight away. The object is usually deleted on the next run loop. This is the preferred way of deleting widgets because it can prevent crashes in some event related situations. If you store a pointer to a QWidget then you should set it to nullptr after using deleteLater() since you don't know for sure when it will actually get deleted:

```
myWidget->deleteLater();
myWidget = nullptr;
```

Destroy() is a function you probably never need to use. It is called automatically by the QWidget destructor and frees up window related system resources. You should just stick to using deleteLater().

So in your example, you are using a timer to hide a widget after x milliseconds. If you want it to be deleted then use this:

```
QTimer::singleShot(tim*1000, &qPopup, &QLabel::deleteLater);
```

Or you can set the delete_on_close flag on your widget and connect the timer to the close() function:

```
qPopup->setAttribute( Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose, true );
QTimer::singleShot(tim*1000, &qPopup, &QLabel::close);
```

Or you can keep using the hide() function but know it won't be deleted unless its the last visible widget in your application.